# SmartGit commit url

Tags: git, smartgit

While you are using the journal window in SmartGit, is there a way to navigate to a specific commit in the browser or get the url of a commit you pushed to the remote server?

Comment: From the *Journal* view, it's not possible. In the *Log* window, *Details* view there is an *Open*-Link for certain platforms, like GitHub.

Comment: I'm asking specifically for SmartGit

Comment: Right, my answer is referring to SmartGit.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm linked to bitbucket repos so this link isn't available.

Comment: Make sure to have the **Bitbucket** **Hosting Provider** configured in the **Preferences**, then you should see an **Open**-Link, too.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!